# How Do I Create a Templated, Swipable View?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have a collection of items, the number of which is not known till runtime.

For each item, I want a view that has a label and a button.

I want to be able to swipe through each view and be able to have the button respond in a way that makes sense for the item.

In a general sense, what is a good way to approach the problem? I looked into creating a paged scrollview with dynamically calculated width, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: A paginated `UICollectionView` maybe?

Comment: Doesn't `UIPageViewController` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

```
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = true
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: One point of clarification: I want the swipable views to be fullscreen. Does this strategy still apply? Most of the tutorials I'm finding online tend to use a UICollectionView to display a table of data on a single screen. Also, sorry if it's a silly question; I'm brand new to iOS development.